# SQL Server licences - per core explanation

Tags: sql-server

This is a general question, I looked into a dedicated hosted server, (6 core CPU).
There is an option to add SQL Server 2016 to it, which I want to do. However, the hosting provider has the following "2 core Licence Pack - a minimum of 4 licenses is required" - that costs 3k, when I spoke to the sales rep, they said that I need to get 3 X 2 core licenses. Is that correct? Does SQL Server need to have the same number of Core lic's as the CPU has?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is about licensing - **not** programming

Comment: Yes, that is correct.